# Visual Studio & Nuget: Package Manager Console commands history?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package

Is there any way to find the commands written in the Package Manager Console, like a history, for my particular project?

Answer (score 1):

From the Package Manager Console you can use the Powershell command `Get-History` to get a history of all commands executed during the current session.

Comment: the current session history can be accessed also by up/down arrows, like in CMD. No need for a command